# CAR duct in same bay as electrical wire

Tags: electrical, hvac, ducts

I'm going to install a cold air return (CAR) duct through an interior wall that has some electrical running through it.  The CAR duct will run vertically, but near the bottom third of the bay there is a single 14-3 electrical wire carrying 110 AC that is running horizontally.

Are there rules against or problems with having CAR ductwork and electrical wiring in the same bay?  Although I can probably route the wire around the duct (using what ever small amount of slack there is in the wire run), it will likely end up touching the duct with very little slack.

Comment: What do you mean by CAR duct?

Comment: CAR means "cold air return" in my HVAC system.

Comment: To be clear, you mean that the Romex will be *outside* the duct, not penetrating it, right?

Comment: @wallyk yes, the wire is outside the duct.